# let R be a subring of $ Q $ contaning $1$. then For every maximal ideal m in R ,the residue field $ R/m$ is finite . TRue/false

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is the following statement is true ??

let R be  a subring of $ Q $ contaning $1$. then

For  every maximal ideal  m in R ,the residue field   $ R/m$  is  finite

i thinks  This  statement  is true  because  every finite  integral  domain  is field....as  R/m  is finite..

Is its  true/false?

pliz give  me any Hints/solution

thanks u......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: I added the "ring-theory" tag to your post.  Cheers!

Comment: *The* subring of $Q$ containing $1$? Which one?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path..im not getting..read my  question  carefully

Comment: Since every ring except $\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ has more than one subring that contains $1$, which of those subrings are you referring to when you use the phrase "let $R$ be **the** subring of $Q$ containing $1$"?

Comment: still im not getting    as   i think  im taking  boths @ Saucy sir

Comment: @SaucyO'Path: I think the question is whether this is true for every (proper?) unital subring of the rationals.

Comment: Btw, am I right in assumeing that $Q=\Bbb Q$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The problem statement does *not* speak of a *proper* subring.